# jQuery closest returns undefined

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

I have a generated jqueryui accordion code like this:

```
<div id="treeview-accordion">
<h3><a href="#" accindex="0">Basic</a></h3>
<div>
    <ul class="navigation-treeview treeview-sanjo" id="yw0">
        <li><span style="font-weight:bold"><a href="/sanjo/site/index"> Home</a></span>
            <ul>
                <li><span> Profile</span>
                    <ul>
                        <li><span><a href="/sanjo/user/profile"> View Profile</a></span></li>
                        <li><span><a href="/sanjo/user/profile/edit"> Update Profile</a></span></li>
                        <li><span><a href="/sanjo/user/profile/changepassword"> Change Password</a></span></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><span> Personnel Management</span>
            <ul>
                <li><span><a href="/sanjo/user/admin"> Manage Personnel</a></span>
                <ul>
                    <li><span><a href="/sanjo/user"> List Personnel</a></span></li>
                    <li><span> Add Personnel</a></span></li>
                </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<h3><a href="#" accindex="0">Basic2</a></h3>
<div>
    <ul class="navigation-treeview treeview-sanjo" id="yw01">
        <li><span style="font-weight:bold"><a href="/sanjo/site/index2"> Home2</a></span>
            <ul>
                <li><span> Profile</span>
                    <ul>
                        <li><span><a href="/sanjo/user/profile2"> View Profile2</a></span></li>
                        <li><span><a href="/sanjo/user/profile/edit2"> Update Profile2</a></span></li>
                        <li><span><a href="/sanjo/user/profile/changepassword2"> Change Password2</a></span></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><span> Personnel Management2</span>
            <ul>
                <li><span><a href="/sanjo/user/admin2"> Manage Personnel2</a></span>
                <ul>
                    <li><span><a href="/sanjo/user2"> List Personnel2</a></span></li>
                    <li><span> Add Personnel2</a></span></li>
                </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and what I want to achieve is to get the attribute "accindex" of the appropriate 'h3' tag depending on the link clicked.

For example,I clicked on "View Profile", and since it is located under the "h3" (Basic), I want to get the value of its accindex attribute, which is "0".

I tried to use closest(), but it is returning "undefined". I can't use parents() either.

How could I accomplish such task? Kindly help me out.

Thanks.

Comment: I really am grateful with all of you answers. Hopefully one day I can become a jquery expert just like all of you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all "View Profile" link is not inside h3, its in the sibling of h3. Try this

When you click on view profile link try this

```
accindex = $(this).closest("div").prev("h3").find("a").attr("accindex");
```

Note: In the above code `this` represents the anchor which is clicked.

Comment: Hmm..I really am amazed that this can be accomplished with just one line of code! (yeah yeah,I am shallow :p)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mrchief/M6PcW/

```
$('a.link').click(function() {
    alert($(this).closest('div').prev('h3').children('a').attr('accindex'));
    return false;
});
```

I modified your markup to add a class to desired href (to make the selection easy).
E.g. `<a class="link" href="/sanjo/user/profile/edit"> Update Profile</a>`

Comment: I replaced "$('a.link')" to "$('a')" because it redirects me to the link if I don't. After that, it worked like a charm!

Comment: It shouldn't as I have `return false` in there (and it doesn't do that in the fiddle).

Comment: Wierd...when I clicked the link from Manage Personnel below, fiddle returns Error 404...the rest just alerts the attribute

Comment: :) That's because I didn't add the class to all hrefs, just a few to show you the concept.

Answer (score 0):

The 'View profile' link is not a child of the `<h3>`, this is why `parents()` and `closest()` did not work.  You need to traverse up the DOM from the link to the `<ul>`, then the `<div>`, then you can get the `<h3>`.

Assuming `this` is the link:

```
$(this).closest('ul.navigation-treeview').closest('div').prev('h3');
```

should get the `<h3>` you want.

From there, get the enclosed `<a>` and its accindex.

```
var acc = $(this).closest('ul.navigation-treeview').closest('div').prev('h3').find('a');
acc.attr('accindex');
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/yWsDx/

EDIT: `$(this).closest('div').prev('h3').find('a')` should be fine, the `.closest('ul.navigation-treeview')` isn't necessary.

Comment: Perfect! I tried the jsfiddle and it worked just like I wanted it to behave. I'll implement it in my codes as soon as I get dressed :D

Comment: I wanted to vote up, but stackoverflow won't let me. I'll vote this up as soon as I can...you just saved my day Rocket,thanks a bunch

Comment: @Macinville: You're welcome.  I'd glad to help.  Keep posting here, and eventually you will have the rep to up-vote :-)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to use 'find' or 'children'.

So to get the attribute in the anchor tag you would do (when using the context of the H3):

```
$("h3 a").attr("accindex");
```

or

```
$("h3").find("a").attr("accindex");
```

or

```
$("h3").children("a").attr("accindex");
```

I am guessing your click event uses the anchor tag as its selection so you may just need to do:

```
$(this).attr("accindex");
```

Click on 'Basic' here.
http://jsfiddle.net/hns2H/1/